# Interpretation of the following R code

Tags: r

The query is to select elements at indices 1,4,7,10,13...

It could be done in several ways, but I do not understand the working of the following :

```
    yVec <- sample(0:999,size = 250,replace = T)
    yVec[c(T,F,F)]
```

Output:
[1] 709 517 437 783 671 860 581 347 279 974 216 776 538 460 985 248 317   288 687 957 938 101
[23] 615 285 106 414 881 488 484 791 246 643 845 553 465  87 993 116 473 635 310 428 965  19
[45] 489 803 604 800 175 516 902 689 881 593 835 398 358 850 791 915 665 167 866 942 320 482
[67] 216 488 681 273 884 970 469 717 127 952 284 695 325 777 792  72 738 791

Comment: akrun has posted a valid response. I want to add, that using T instead of TRUE and F instead of FALSE is bad practice and should be avoided. The gain in code shortness is small, the risk, that at some time somebody defines variables T or F with some other value than TRUE and FALSE is large. Set `T<-0` and the above code will not work anymore.

Comment: @Bernhard Thank you for the advice, I will keep it in mind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vector `c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE)` is recycling to the entire vector and will extract the 1st, 4th, 7th, etc values of the `vector`.  It is similar to replicating the logical vector to the length of the vector.

```
yVec[rep(c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE), length.out = length(yVec))]
```

Wherever the logical vector is TRUE, it will extract the corresponding element in 'yVec'.

Comment: So it is because of recycling, thank you pointing that out. My query is solved.